# connecting to VM instance having no external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to a google cloud VM instance having no external IP address via `cloud shell` and `cloud SDK`.

Google document says that we can connect it using IAP
Connecting through IAP: **refer** [using IAP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host)

a) Grant the `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` role to the user that wants to connect to the **VM**.

b) Connect to the **VM** using below command

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-name --zone zone
```

OR
Using `IAP` for `TCP` forwarding: refer [using TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)
we can also connect by setting a ingress firewall rule for `IP` `'35.235.240.0/20'` with port `TCP:22`
and select a `IAM` role Select `Cloud IAP > IAP-Secured Tunnel User`

what's the difference between these two different approach and what's the difference in these two separate IAM roles

```
roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor
IAP-secured Tunnel User
```

I am new to cloud so please bear with my basic knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same thing. Look at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access#roles)

> IAP-Secured Tunnel User (roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor)

You have the display name of the role: `IAP-Secured Tunnel User` that you see in the GUI, and you have the technical name of the role `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` that you have to use in the script and CLI

Comment: yes. I saw there's only one name which's getting displayed as "IAP-Secured Tunnel User". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The link mentioned in the question ("refer [using IAP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host)") actually points to the
[Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses > Connecting through a bastion host](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host).
Connection through a **bastion host** is another method apart from access via IAP.

As described in the document [Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses > Connecting through IAP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap),

> IAP's TCP forwarding feature wraps an SSH connection inside HTTPS.
> IAP's TCP forwarding feature then sends it to the remote instance.

Therefore both parts of the question (before OR and after OR) belong to the same access method: [Connect using Identity-Aware Proxy for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap). Hence the answer to the first question is **"no difference"** because all of that describes how the IAP TCP forwarding works and those are the steps to set it up and use:

**1.** Create a firewall rule that:

- applies to all VM instances that you want to be accessible by using IAP;
- allows ingress traffic from the IP range `35.235.240.0/20` (this range contains all IP addresses that IAP uses for TCP forwarding);
- allows connections to all ports that you want to be accessible by using IAP TCP forwarding, for example, port `22` for SSH.

**2.** Grant permissions to use IAP:

- Use GCP Console or gcloud to add a role `IAP-Secured Tunnel User` (`roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor`) to users.
  Note: Users with `Owner` access to a project **always have permission** to use IAP for TCP forwarding.

**3.** Connect to the target VM with one of the following tools:

- GCP Console: use the `SSH` button in the Cloud Console;
- `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME`

There's an important explanation of how IAP TCP forwarding is invoked for accessing a VM instance without Public IP. See [Identity-Aware Proxy > Doc > Using IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding):

NOTE. If the instance doesn't have a Public IP address, the connection **automatically uses IAP TCP tunneling**. If the instance does have a public IP address, the connection uses the public IP address instead of IAP TCP tunneling.
You can use the `--tunnel-through-iap` flag so that `gcloud compute ssh` always uses IAP TCP tunneling.

As already noted by [guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere), `roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` and `IAP-secured Tunnel User` are not the different IAM roles, but the **Role Name** and the **Role Title** of the same Role. There is one more  resource that represents this in a convenient form:
[Cloud IAM > Doc > Understanding roles > Predefined roles > Cloud IAP roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-iap-roles)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. I will certainly take a look at this.